# Apache conf for URL access for Wampserver?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with en URL...

I work with Wampserver 3.0.6.

I'm trying to access fallowing file : `http://localhost.monurl.fr/categorie/1_320_192.jpg`

The value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is "*/**categorie.php**/1_320_192.jpg`

The problem is it should be `/catimage.php` because of the following rewrite rule :

`RewriteRule ^categorie/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).jpg$ catimage.php?catid=$1&dstWidth=$2&dstHeight=$3 [QSA,L]`

Apache doesn't seem to access the .htaccess file in that case... And it works in other pages.

Do you have any idea ? Apache conf maybe ?

Comment: Sounds like you have another rewrite rule rewriting to `category.php` that is applied _before_ your rule is considered. You will need to change the order of rules.

Comment: I tried to empty the .htaccess file. The problem stay the same (that's why I think it is Apache fault).

Comment: 1. Make sure you do not look at a cached result, disable / empty your browsers cache or make a _deep reload_. 2. It might be that there are additional rules at other locations, other `.htaccess` style files or rules inside the http servers host configration which is the preferred place to define such rules anyway. And 3. it might be that "content negotiation" is enabled, disable it by adding `Options -MultiViews`.